# Route some questions to [url-routing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Some one recently created [url-routing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-routing). At time of writing, there are [<s>75...56</s> <s>20</s> 0 candidate questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+MVC+routing+-%5Burl-routing%5D) for this new tag. Anyone care to lend a hand applying it?

As always, remember to make ***all*** appropriate edits when re-tagging. Be sure to fix spelling & grammar while you're at it.

If anyone thinks of other good queries for candidate questions, please add them here as well. We can use this post to track searches and progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done.

I had a little bit of trouble coming up with titles for these questions, so if anyone wants to go through and try to fix some of the titles, that'd be nice. I did find one false positive that didn't require the tag [url-routing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-routing) though:

> [Ultimate Tic Tac Toe A.K.A. Tic Tactics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101253/ultimate-tic-tac-toe-a-k-a-tic-tactics)